# Python tool to balance parentheses, quotes, and brackets

Tags: python

Does anyone know of an already-written Python script, tool, or editor that will check for unbalanced multi-line tokens? (parentheses, quotes, {}, [], etc.)

I've been writing Python code in IDLE, and every so often I'll get "EOF token in multi-line statement" and start swearing, because it means that somewhere in about 200 lines of code I forgot a closing parenthesis or quote and IDLE can't tell me where.  This seems like a fairly straightforward thing, I just don't really have the time or headspace to work it out myself right now.

Much thanks

Comment: eclipse pydev works OK for this... and I am pretty sure there is support for this in emacs etc.

Comment: Is the Syntax-coloring broken?  Usually that tells you everything you need to know?

Comment: it doesn't color (), {}, or [] statements; it only highlights it when you type the closing token.  If I didn't notice the highlighting, or if I typed the line and then messed with stuff inside the parentheses, it doesn't really help.

Comment: So it works, but you're choosing to ignore it?  That doesn't seem right.  I don't get the problem yet.  Could you describe the interaction that leads to the problem?

Comment: Example 1: I type, for example, `log_file.write( something )`, go do something else, then realize I want the log file to say something a bit different, and go back and put in something like `str(datetime.now()) + "stuff" + string name + str(numeric operations) +  "stuff"` etc. in place of `somestuff`.  This may stretch over a few lines, and if I have enough nested calls, I make a mistake with my parentheses somewhere; if I have quotes inside my string literals, I may screw those up too. If i'm looking at something else while I'm typing, I miss the temporary highlighting.

Comment: Example 2: I type `log_file.write(`, realize I don't know what I want to put there, go work on the next thing I wanted to fix, and completely forget about it.  
  
Example 3: I type a string literal assignment, such as `path = r'C:\folder\folder\'` and forget to escape the last backslash. Because there's nothing after it on that line, syntax coloring doesn't tell me that the string literal hasn't ended.  If I type `asdsdf` after it on that line, it shows up green.  But the lines after that don't.

Comment: To be fair, these could be fairly well avoided by not coding when sleep-deprived, but that's really not an option for me.

Comment: @Rowan: Please don't add comments to a question you own.  Please make this information a first-class part of the question, not a hard-to-read comment attached to the question.  You own the question.  You can fix it to make it crystal clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) with [PyDev](http://pydev.org/).  It's very good for this sort of thing, and lots more.

Comment: Links are yay.  Thanks, I'll check these out.

Answer (score 1):

[emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) will automatically highlight matching pairs of parentheses/brackets/quotes/etc. as you type them, and it will inform you immediately if you mismatch them (e.g. if you type a `[` followed by a `)`).  I'm sure vim also does this, but since I don't use vim, I can't say with certainty.

Comment: vim definitely does that. It also allows jumping to the paired element by pressing `%`.

Comment: Augh, I can't help thinking of text-only consoles whenever I think of emacs or vim.  I haven't used them since I was a kid.

Answer (score 0):

[PyDev](http://www.pydev.org) is the best IDE to develop in Python. Has this feature and a lot of more.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the vim text editor, there is a [syntax highlighter for Python](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=790) that might be of some help.  Vim's python indenting rules also line up a new line with an unmatched open parenthesis from the previous line.  That's been my visual cue that something is unbalanced.